# exporting mysql data to excel raises unexpected datetime.datetime

Tags: python, mysql, xlwt

I have mysql data like this

> id | name | time_stamp |

which time_stamp field contains data in datetime format

So this is the code to export that mysql data to xls :

```
w = Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet("Sheet Title") # worksheet name

# Database connection
con = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='', passwd='', db='dbtest')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT name, time_stamp FROM log")

# iterate row and col
rowNum = 0
colNum = 0

# Print all to worksheet
for row in cur.fetchall():
   ws.write(rowNum, colNum, row)
   rowNum =+1
   colNum =+1
```

and this is the results :

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
 return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
 response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
 reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
 response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
 reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
 rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/pi/script/app2.py", line 132, in report
 ws.write(rowNum, colNum, row)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
 self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 252, in write
 self.__rich_text_helper(col, label, style, style_index)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlwt/Row.py", line 278, in __rich_text_helper
 raise Exception ("Unexpected data type %r" % type(data))
Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I notice there's error with datetime format data from the SQL data while trying to export to XLS. Is there a way to export datetime data from SQL to XLS? Already trying several solutions from stackoverflow but to no avail

Comment: Excel doesn't actually have dates, only numbers formatted to appear as dates. Translate your datetime into a number of days since 31 December 1899: `(mydatetime - datetime.datetime(1899,12,31)).days`

Comment: i do workaround by saving the dates into varchar datatype and it seems to work. but i will try your method to reduce mistype data so it won't be confused  with normal varchar datatype